# Why using this is not legal in strict mode

Tags: javascript, jshint, strict-mode

I have the following code :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('gestion').controller(
        'controller',
        controller);

    controller.$inject = ['$mdDialog',
            'locals'];

    function controller($mdDialog, locals) {
        var pm = this;

        pm.cancel = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        pm.validate = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
            locals.parentScope.remove();
        };
    }
})();
```

The problem is that when I run `jshint` I get this warning message:

> If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation, its
>   'this' value will be undefined.

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

I don't know why this question has been marked as duplicated.

## Edit 2:

I solved the problem when I used `Controller` instead of `controller`, this has to deal with the `Constructor Invocation Pattern`, since you should capitalise the first character of the name of a function when you need to construct the object by "new" keyword, which `var pm = this` does in this case.

Comment: That seems like a warning, `jshint` is probably not aware of angular context calls so it's printing that

Comment: It is legal. That's a warning not an error.

Comment: If you don't think this is a duplicate, please explain why the answers to the duplicate don't solve your problem. Don't just say you don't know why it's a duplicate, that doesn't help anybody understand *why* you don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @DonaldDuck updated with the solution, which has nothing related to the referenced answer.